# oracle: Count the classes start each month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count of classes to start each month.

```
select
   to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON'),
   count(START_DATE_TIME)
from
   SECTION
having 
   count(START_DATE_TIME) > 1
group by 
   START_DATE_TIME
```

**It give me this output**

```
MAY 4
APR 3
MAY 2
JUN 2
APR 2
JUL 7
JUL 7
JUN 3
APR 4
MAY 2
APR 6
MAY 4
JUN 2
JUN 2
JUN 3
MAY 5
JUN 2
APR 3
MAY 3
JUN 3
MAY 2
APR 2
MAY 3
```

**I need a output similar to this**

```
Start_Month Count 
July        14 
June        17 
April       21
May         26
```

Comment: use this "to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON')" in your count, group by, having and order by.

Comment: I tried this but it wont work

Answer (score 1):

Use "to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON')" in all of your count, group by, having and order by.

```
select
   to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON') as Start_Month ,
   count(to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON')) as Count 
from
   SECTION
having 
   count(to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON')) > 1
group by 
   to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON')
order by 
   count(to_char(START_DATE_TIME,'MON'));
```

Comment: how I add the column name is Start_Month and count like Start_Month  Count 
July        14 
June        17 
April       21
May         26

Comment: So, did you run anonyXmous' query? It should work just fine. If you're asking how to *rename* column header, then use the **alias**.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `group by START_DATE_TIME` you tell the DBMS you want one result row per START_DATE_TIME. But what you actually want is one result row per month, so group by month instead.
2. `count(START_DATE_TIME)` counts the rows for which START_DATE_TIME is not null. As you group by this date, this makes no sense. Count the rows unconditionally instead (`COUNT(*)`).
3. `having count(START_DATE_TIME) > 1` occurs after `GROUP BY` of course and should hence be placed behind it. It looks strange to see it in the wrong place. Moreover: What are you trying to achieve with this condition? You get one result row per START_DATE_TIME, because there is at least one record for the date in the table. So of course this connition is true for all dates. (Except for null, if START_DATE_TIME is nullable. But then you'd merely apply `WHERE START_DATE_TIME IS NOT NULL`.)

The query corrected:

```
select
  to_char(start_date_time, 'Month') as "Start_Month",
  count(*) as "Count"
from section
group by to_char(start_date_time, 'Month')
order by "Count";
```

BTW: I guess you are aware that you are looking at months regardless of the year. If you want to change this, change the `TO_CHAR` format accordingly.